# How can I make a Map with different types that extend a base?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have this map:

```
class BaseClass {
    constructor() {}
    baseMethod(myArgs: any) {console.log(myArgs);}
}

const myMap: Map<string, BaseClass> = new Map();
```

If I have many classes like such

```
class A extends BaseClass {
    propertyNotOnBaseClass: string;

    constructor() {}
    baseMethod(digit: number) {console.log(digit ** 2);}
}

// class B extends BaseClass {...
```

and add them to the map

```
const A_Instance = new A();

function addToMap(classToAdd) {
   myMap.set(classToAdd.constructor.name, classToAdd);
}

addToMap(A_Instance);
```

...how can I access property `propertyNotOnBaseClass` from the map without casting it?

My current code is

```
myMap.get("A")!.propertyNotOnBaseClass...
```

and I just `@ts-ignore` it. However, I'm sure there's a more elegant solution-- I just can't find it.

Can anyone help? :)

(for reference, I'm fairly new to TypeScript)

Comment: Is your map trying to store a reference to the `class A` or an *instance* of class A?  I think you meant `myMap.set(A.constructor.name, A_Instance);`  You can store the class itself but you would need to change your map type to `Map<string, typeof BaseClass>`.

Comment: The way that a `Map` is typed, it doesn't know that the key at `"A"` is anything other than a `BaseClass` so there's not really an elegant solution to this (using `Map`, that is).  You would have to use a "type guard" to make sure that the value your received has  `propertyNotOnBaseClass`.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of a `Map` is such that all of the elements have the same type.  In this case that type is `BaseType`.

It sounds like you don't really want a `Map` because you want specific keys to be associated with specific value types.  I have created a custom class that you can use as an alternative to the built-in `Map` object to get very specific type annotations.

Since you are new to Typescript you probably won't understand the "How It Works" part, but using it should be simple and will resolve a lot of issues.

#### TypedMap Class

```
class TypedMap<T = {}> {
  data: T;

  constructor() {
    this.data = {} as T;
  }

  set<K extends PropertyKey, V extends (K extends keyof T ? T[K] : any)>(
    key: K, value: V
  ): asserts this is TypedMap<T & { [k in K]: V }> {
    this.data = {
      ...this.data,
      [key]: value
    }
  }

  get<K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K] {
    return this.data[key];
  }
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/ND5kVm)

#### How It Works

Our class is a wrapper around a plain object `this.data` which provides `get()` and `set()` functionality comparable to a `Map`.  The generic `T` describes the current type of the `this.data` object.

We always start with an empty object so `T` is `{}`.  Whenever we call `set()`, the `asserts this is` return type changes the value of `T` to include our new key and value.  [edited: handling of overrides] If a value already exists for this key then we cannot set it to an incompatible type, which we handle by `V extends (K extends keyof T ? T[K] : any)`. This allows us to narrow a key's value type but not change it to something different.

`set()` must be called with a `key` that has a string literal type and not just type `string` in order to get proper type inference for specific keys.  So `"A"` is fine but `A.constructor.name` is a problem because that variable has type `string` instead of type `"A"`.

When you call `get()` the returned type will be the type associated with that key in `T`.  You must pass a valid key of `T`.

#### Usage

When you create the map, you have to assign type `TypedMap` (the same as `TypedMap<{}>`) to the variable in order to avoid the error *"Assertions require every name in the call target to be declared with an explicit type annotation."*

```
const myMap: TypedMap = new TypedMap();
```

You can set different keys with different value types:

```
myMap.set("A", new A());
myMap.set("Base", new BaseClass());
```

And when you retrieve those keys, you get the right type!

```
const a = myMap.get("A"); // type: A
const base = myMap.get("Base"); // type: BaseClass
```

When overwriting an existing key, you can only pass a value that is assignable to the current type:

```
myMap.set("Base", new A());
const changed = myMap.get("Base"); // type: A
```

Comment: I’m kind of surprised you can alter the type of an existing property in a non-narrowing way.

Comment: @jcalz it seems to work.  Is there any reason that this shouldn't be done?

Comment: I didn't have a chance to check what it was doing yet so I didn't know how to elaborate (on mobile).  Assertion functions can narrow but not widen or change to an unrelated type; if you try to do it it will just be ignored.  See [here](https://tsplay.dev/WzyOkm): you get the unfortunate effect where, `m.set("k", 123); m.set("k", "abc"); m.get("k")` will apparently produce a `number` at compile time but a `string` at runtime.  The intended change with `m.set("k", "abc")` never happens because the compiler does not see `TypedMap<{k: string}>` as assignable to `TypedMap<{k: number}>`.

Comment: Personally I'd say you should either make it impossible to change the type of an already-set key, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxoYxN), or you should make it that you can narrow but not do anything else, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQAVJw).  I prefer the former, since it behaves more like normal assignment.

Comment: @jcalz I guess it worked in my example code because I was narrowing the type when going from `Base` to `A`.  But I didn't realize that's what I was doing :)